# Referenced project content files not being copied to linux-x64 platform output directory

Tags: c#, linux, xml, configuration, msbuild

I have the following solution structure and dependency chain:

```
Solution layout:

[Solution]
     |
     +----[Project P1, .NET 6 Console App]
     |         |
     |         +---- ...
     |         |
     |         +----[Settings folder]
     |                   |
     |                   +----....
     |                   |
     |                   +----appsettings.json
     |
     |          
     +----[Project P2, .NET Standard]
     |         |
     |         +----[Settings folder]
     |                   |
     |                   +----WebPerfCounter.json
     |
     +----[Project P3, .NET Standard]

Dependency chain:

[Project P3] <---Ref By---- [Project P2] <---Ref By--- [Project P1]
                                |
                +---------------+
                |
           <ItemGroup>
             <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Settings\WebPerfCounter.json">
               <CopyToOutputPath>Always</CopyToOutputPath>
               <TargetPath>Settings\WebPerfCounter.json</TargetPath>
             </ContentWithTargetPath>
           </ItemGroup>
```

When I build the solution, *two* platform folders for Project P1 are created: *win-x64* and *linux-x64* because I have `<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` in P1.csproj.

The former folder has the *WebPerfCounter.json* file as expected, but the *linux-x64* folder does not.

What can be done so the *WebPerfCounter.json* file in Project P2 is copied to the Linux platform folder?

*EDIT*: I tried copying using `<Target><Copy /><Target>` to no avail, as shown below,

*P2.csproj*:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="Current">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <RootNamespace>P2</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>P2</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Title></Title>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Settings\WebPerfCounter.json">
      <CopyToOutputPath>Always</CopyToOutputPath>
      <TargetPath>Settings\WebPerfCounter.json</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="prometheus-net" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\P3\P3.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="PublishPerfCounterConfigFiles" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <JsonPerfCounterConfigFiles Include="Settings\*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Copying performance counter configuration now." Importance="high" Runtime="*" />
    <Copy DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)Settings" SourceFiles="@(JsonPerfCounterConfigFiles)"
      Runtime="*" Architecture="*" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Although I've added a `<Message>` tag to the target, it does not show in Visual Studio Output pane when I publish P1 to a folder.

Comment: How did you try to use the `Copy` task? A `ProjectReference` will not include all the files in a referenced project. A manual `Copy` step can easily be added to handle the `WebPerfCounter.json` file. Can you provide a simple example of how you tried to add the `Copy`?

Comment: @JonathanDodds I've just edited the question.

Comment: What is your level of experience with and knowledge of [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: @JonathanDodds I have some experience with MSBuild.exe.

Comment: Why is `PublishPerfCounterConfigFiles` set to run `AfterTargets="Publish"`? Why do you have `Runtime` and `Architecture` parameters on your [`Copy` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2022)?  What are you expecting `ContentWithTargetPath` to do for you?